# Is there any method to get list of Product Attributes in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want a list of Product Attributes.I tried following code :-

```
<?php

    namespace Wizzy\Search\Model\Admin\Source;
    
    use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute;
    
    class AllAttributesList
    {
        protected $_attributeFactory;
    
        public function __construct(Attribute $attributeFactory)
        {
            $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
        }
    
        public function toOptionArray()
        {
            $attributeInfo = $this->_attributeFactory->getCollection();
            foreach ($attributeInfo as $attributes) {
                $options[] = [
                    'value' => $attributes->getData('attribute_code'),
                    'label' => $attributes->getData('frontend_label') . " (" . $attributes->getData('attribute_code') . ")",
                ];
            }

            return $options;
        }
    }
```

But I want the list of this page :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwjcc.png

Answer (score 0):

Get an eav_attribute collection and filter on entity_type product ?

EDIT : Full solution

```
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\CollectionFactory

/**
 *
 * @param CollectionFactory $attributeFactory
 * @param Config    $eavConfig
 */
public function __construct(
    CollectionFactory $attributeFactory,
    Config $eavConfig
)
{
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
}
```

And then retrieve the collection

```
$collection = $this->attributeFactory->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $this->eavConfig->getEntityType(ProductEntityType::ENTITY)->getEntityTypeId());
```

You can also directly replace the full `$this->eavConfig->getEntityType(ProductEntityType::ENTITY)->getEntityTypeId()` by the number 3 or 4 which is the type id if you check it in database. This way you don't even have to call for eavConfig.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/205277)

Comment: @Msquare Well it actually does...adding a `?` doesn't mean i'm asking a question. It only means doest it fullfill your needs. Can provide more details if needed.

Comment: can you please post a solution ?

Comment: @smitkandiya You will find complete solution there